# can burst and legend of mapview function in R be both enabled?

Tags: r

If the burst and legend are both set to TRUE, it doesnt show the legend, just shows like this

[image]

But I need to disable burst, then it can show the legend. How to both enable showing multilayer and legend?

Comment: This is currently not possible. This was a deliberate choice because leaflet was, so far, not able to link legends to layers which means that with more that 2-3 layers one will not see all legends because they are outside the viewer regions as they are simply plotted one below the other. Last week, leaflet integrated an option to link legends to their respective layers so that when the layer is switched off so is the legend. I will now re-implement burst to allow for legends but this may take a bit of time. I will report back once this is available.